# Highlight one side border on hover - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to provide an interface that allows the users to create a table structure. This is similar to how Microsoft Word provides the insert table functionality. I am using JavaScript for this purpose.

User should be able to select a border (line) and delete it to merge the cells. So, I have to highlight a one side border of a cell to be able to visualize it.

Is it possible to identify the mouse position when it moves on the border?

Comment: Just using plain Javascript, or libraries like Jquery are OK?

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK, with Jquery, there here is a tutorial showing how to identify mouse coordinates.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

Source : [http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch the mouse hover event, get the absolute cell position (e.g. with jQuery), compare it to the mouse pointers' position and then have a little switch statement decide which border to highlight.

Similar action if you gonna "delete" a border.